# In python can two different objects of same class have different no of variables

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
class car:
    pass

firstcar = car()
secondcar = car()

firstcar.wheels = 4
print(firstcar.wheels)
```

> output: 4

But when I try `print(type(secondcar.wheels))` it gives me **AttributeError**

1. When I create **c1.wheels** then why **wheels** is not created as an instance variable for object c2.
2. If **wheels** is not created for c2 then is it that object of same class can have different number of instance variables in python.

Comment: what is c1? and c2

Comment: Really Sorry... c1 is equal to firstcar and c2 is equal to secondcar

Answer (score 4):

You're adding an attribute of `wheels` to the **instance** `firstcar` not to the `car` **class**.

Each instance has a `__dict__` attribute, which holds all other attributes, and effectively all you're doing with

```
firstcar.wheels=4
```

is

```
firstcar .__dict__[wheels]=4 
#nb. this won't actually work as you cant assign to object __dict__s this way; 
#it's just an analogy!
```

This might be clearer now why this doesn't affect secondcar

```
firstcar = car()
secondcar = car()

firstcar.wheels=4

print(firstcar.__dict__) #{'wheels': 4}
print(secondcar.__dict__)#{}
```

In contrast you can actually add variables to classes in this way:

```
class car:
    pass

car.wheels=""

firstcar = car()
secondcar = car()

firstcar.wheels = 4
print(firstcar.wheels)
print(secondcar.wheels)
```

Which will not give you an attribute error.  In fact you can add attributes to the class after you create your instances and still avoid the error.

(This is just for explanation, not suggesting to use it in real life, it could lead to some very confusing code!)

Comment: nb. using eg `print(firstcar.__dict__)` prints all attributes of an instance, which is useful for further exploring how this works.

Comment: But since an object is an instance of a class, how can they have different no of variables

Comment: @AshokKumar because they can!  Being able to dynamically add attributes to classes and objects is just part of how Python works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Two objects of the same class can have different no. of instance variables, But they always have the same no. of class variables.

Comment: Is it in python or other languages also support different no of variables for different objects of same class.

Comment: @AshokKumar This is true for all programming languages which support OOP.